# Different jQuery on first load with expiration time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate posts like [this](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/). It takes longer to animate opacity on first load and less time to animate opacity on second, after refreshing the page. It also looks like the timer is set to ~5 minutes (works across all tabs).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(0)").delay(300).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(1)").delay(900).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(2)").delay(1500).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(3)").delay(2100).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(4)").delay(2700).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(5)").delay(3300).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(6)").delay(3900).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);

  jQuery(".floating-box:eq(7)").delay(4500).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
h2 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.floating-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #4F69F8;
}

.floating-box {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-out;
  will-change: opacity;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Opacity Animation</h2>

<div class="floating-box">First Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Second Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Third Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Fourth Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Fifth Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Sixth Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Seventh Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Eighth Floating box</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hc61tx28/6/

Comment: Could you please add your HTML to the question so we can see a working example of what you have. We cannot debug an animation without seeing it in action. Also note that CSS keyframes is generally a much better solution to requirements like this.

Comment: Thanks, added working example.

Comment: what is your question anw?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt my question is how to make animations slow on first load and fast after that (with F5), with expiration time 10 minutes. This is for homepage.